# Removing Images with CSS and not adjusting HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm a super beginner and I'm trying to remove 3 images from an HTML page using CSS only. I feel like I've tried everything and can't figure it out.

Here is the HTML code:

```
body>
<header>
    <h1>Ulimate Frisbee History</h1>
    <nav>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="teams.html">Teams</a>
        <a href="history.html" class = "active">History</a>
        <a href="http://www.example.org/index.html" target="_blank">USA Ultimate</a>
    </nav>
</header>
    <main>
        <aside class = "left">
        <a href="https://commons.example.org/wiki/File%3AUltimate_Frisbee%2C_Jul_2009_-_17.jpg"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Ultimate_Frisbee%2C_Jul_2009_-_19.jpg" alt="Creative Common Ultimate Photo" title="By Ed Yourdon [CC BY-SA 2.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0)], via Wikimedia Commons"/> </a>

        <a href="https://commons.example.org/wiki/File%3AUltimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg"><img alt="Ultimate Frisbee Colorado Cup 2005" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7d/Ultimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg/512px-Ultimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg"/></a>


        <a href="https://www.example.com/photos/paradisecoastie/15409853738/" title="Ultimate Frisbee"><img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3948/15409853738_7dbfbfbac7_k.jpg"  alt="Ultimate Frisbee"></a>
    </aside>
    <section class = "right">
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove an element from the page with CSS only, use `display:  none`.

However, you will have to target the images in some way. The code below, for example, removes all images:

```css
img {
  display: none;
}
```

If you only wanted to remove some of the images, give each of these images a certain class name (eg. `image-to-remove`), and use the following code:

```css
.image-to-remove {
  display: none;
}
```

Or, if you wanted to remove all images inside a certain container (which might be the `aside` for you) you could hide that whole element:

```css
aside {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you always can do to remove elements from the document completely is to use following CSS rule:

```
display: none
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to remove the images just using CSS, I believe you should be able to give your all your images a classname like so:

```
    <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AUltimate_Frisbee%2C_Jul_2009_-_17.jpg"><img class="hiddenImage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Ultimate_Frisbee%2C_Jul_2009_-_19.jpg" alt="Creative Common Ultimate Photo" title="By Ed Yourdon [CC BY-SA 2.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0)], via Wikimedia Commons"/> </a>
```

*remember to add "class="hiddenImage" to all your images that you want to hide,

And then in your CSS file you can set them to not display by using:

.hiddenImage {
display:none
}

Feel free to let me know if this works! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to hide the 3 images inside the aside:

```
<aside class="left">
    ...
</aside>
```

You simply have to hide the whole container in your CSS

```
aside.left {
    display: none;
}
```

And if you were able to delete those images in html it would be a better solution since they won't have to be loaded unnecessarily